# docker gradle java windows git build local dependency projects best practise

Tags: docker

I have 1 gradle java Project-A that depends on 2 other gradle java Project-B and also Project-C. All 3 projects build locally using `build.gradle` and Project-A `build.gradle` contains:

```
implementation project(':Project-B')
implementation project(':Project-C')
```

and Project A `settings.gradle` contains:

```
include ':Project-B'
project(':Project-B').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project-B')
include ':Project-C'
project(':Project-C').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../Project-C')
```

All 3 projects have separate private Git repo (because in future other projects depend on B and C).

So that's fine. Now I want to dockerise project-A. Its `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM gradle:jdk11-alpine AS builder
COPY ./ ./
RUN gradle build

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.6_10-alpine
COPY --from=builder *.jar Project-A.jar
CMD ["java -jar Project-A.jar"]
```

The `docker build .` for Project-A is giving an error:

```
#11 51.17 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
#11 51.17
#11 51.17 * What went wrong:
#11 51.17 Could not determine the dependencies of task ':bootJar'.
#11 51.17 > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
#11 51.17    > Could not resolve project :project-B.
#11 51.17      Required by:
#11 51.17          project :
#11 51.17       > No matching configuration of project :project-B was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
#11 51.17           - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
#11 51.17    > Could not resolve project :project-C.
#11 51.17      Required by:
#11 51.18          project :
#11 51.18       > No matching configuration of project :project-C was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
#11 51.18           - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

So, what's best practise to get a `Dockerfile` to build `Project-B` and `Project-C` ? i.e. the respective jar aren't published anywhere else and have to be built along with `Project-A`

The `bootJar` task is merely:

```
bootJar {
    archiveBaseName = 'Project-A'
    archiveVersion =  '0.1.0'
}
```

Basically, a locally run `gradle build` can resolve the underlying projects, but a locally run `docker build .` cannot. What `COPY` step am I missing?

Comment: "*So, what's best practise to get a `Dockerfile` to build `Project-B` and `Project-C` ?*" - Don't. The current setup is not portable (i.e. the exact checkout location(s) are assumed to always be the same). I suggest to use a nexus, artifactory or other maven-repository, bulid `Project-B` and `Project-C` independently, push them to said repository and then pull them from the maven repository to build `Project-A`.

Comment: @Turing85 is there a way to `copy` the git repos into the `Dockerfile` ? ... and then build them all...

Comment: Yes. But - as I said - I would not recommend doing this.